# C++ memory writing without API

Tags: multithreading, memory, process, ram, overwrite

How do I enable my program to read/write another process's memory in C++ without using anything like Windows.h?

I'm running on visual studio in windows 10.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you can't. Process memory management is inherently OS specific so you need to work with the OS.

Comment: Is there a multi-platform solution and if not, would you recommend the Windows.h method?